# Get-WmiObject Win32_ServerFeature Access Remote Server Roles and features

Tags: wmi, windows-server-2012, powershell-remoting, get-wmiobject

Accessing Roles and Features from the Remote server.

i tries the following PowerShell script to get the roles and features from the remote server.

Get-WmiObject -Computer  "serverName" -query 'select * from Win32_ServerFeature'

but the problem is i could not identify additional details like if the given object from the collection is Feature or role. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found another alternative by using `Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName` where i can filter `featuretype` and get separate results for roles and features for remote machines.

For example:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $ServerName | Where-Object {($_.InstallState -eq “installed”) -and ($_.FeatureType -eq “Role Service”)}
```